# Glew isn't initializing

Tags: opengl, c++, glew

I making a game on visual studio, I am still learning though. SO I create the window the context and then initialize glew. Glew doesn't initialize I just get a self-created error(cout written by me) so if you guys could tell me how I can get deeper into the problem and find out what the actual problem is. I have researched but there is no exact answer to my question/problem.

EDIT: I have tried glExperimental.

Comment: Have you made the context current before trying to initialize GLEW?

Comment: Tell us how you create the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately [the GLEW source code is available](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), so we can check that and determine possible causes.

The main reason why GLEW will fail to initialize is if there is no GL context when you call glewInit.  This is the first check done by glewInit and it will return GLEW_ERROR_NO_GL_VERSION.

Possible causes for that include:

- You called glewInit before creating your context or making it current.
- Your context failed to create.
- Your context is not current.

The next reason why glewInit may fail is if the GL version string is malformed.  glewInit checks for the presence of a dot ('.') in the string, and also checks that the last character of the major version is between '0' and '9'.  If these checks fail it will also return GLEW_ERROR_NO_GL_VERSION.

The final reason why glewInit may fail is if your OpenGL implementation is GL 1.0 only (no modern GL implementation - not even the software implementation on Windows - is 1.0, but IIRC it will fail this check on an original 3DFX Voodoo graphics from 1996).  In this case it will return GLEW_ERROR_GL_VERSION_10_ONLY.

Otherwise glewInit will succeed.

Setting glewExperimental has *nothing* to do with whether or not glewInit succeeds; what this does is relax some of the stricter (but more correct) extension verification.

In your case your should verify the following:

- Check the *actual* error returned by glewInit as it will tell you what went wrong.
- Check that your Window creation succeeded.
- Check that your context creation succeeded.
- Check that your context is current (e.g via wglMakeCurrent) before calling glewInit.
- Check your GL renderer and version by calling glGetString (GL_RENDERER) and glGetString (GL_VERSION) - these are both GL 1.1 and so are not dependent on GLEW; you can safely call them even if glewInit fails.
- Check that your GPU actually supports the functionality your trying to access; if you call glewInit, if you check e.g GLEW_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, but if your GPU doesn't support that extension, then you can't use it and nothing GLEW does can make it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As per the very first sample in the [basic GLEW documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html), if `glewInit()` doesn't succeed, it returns an error code.  If you pass that error code to `glewGetErrorString(errorCode)`, that will give you a human-readable string describing what the error was, which presumably will guide you toward finding out what you're doing wrong.

But if I was a betting person, I'd bet that you haven't actually created an OpenGL context before trying to initialise GLEW.  That's usually the problem that people run into.

But you've provided no code to show what you're doing and you haven't described the specifics of the problem you're having (which function call failed, how it failed, what error code it returned, etc;  you haven't even actually told us that it was `glewInit()` which failed;  my comments above had to take that as an assumption), so it's hard to actually give you any assistance beyond pointing you to the documentation (link above).

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any details, but make sure you initialize OpenGL first and make sure that this initialization works. Usuaully glew itself is fairly foolproof. If you still have problems then give my answer a comment and I will take a look.